# argument principle and Roche theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ \subset C$ be a region containing $(0; 1)$ and let $$ be a meromorphic function on $$, which
has no zeros and no poles on $\partial(0;1)$. If $$ has a zero at $0$ and if $Re() > 0 $for every
$\in \partial(0;1)$, shows that $$ has a pole in (0;1)

My idea: Suppose $f$ does not have a pole in $D(0;1)$ and as $f$ be a meromorphic function on $U$.
By arguement principle,  the line integral = # of zeros - # of poles = # of zeros - 0 = winding number ( $f \circ \gamma, 0$ ). I know the winding number should be $1$ but i dont understand how to make use the $Re(f) > 0$,is there any hint ?

Comment: You’re trying to show the wrong thing. Draw a picture. If the real part is everywhere positive, can the image wind around the origin?

Comment: @TedShifrin  The image of ∘ cannot wind around the origin since the Re(f) > 0 which means it will shift to the right half-plane. Then the winding number should be 0 ?

Comment: Right, the winding number is $0$.

Comment: Alternatively: If $f$ has no poles in $D$ then $u(z) = \operatorname{Re}f(z)$ is harmonic and has the mean-value property, so that $u(0) > 0$. This follows also from Cauchy's integral formula. – Do you have to use Rouché's theorem?

Comment: @MartinR The question does not restrict me to use Rouche theorem but I am interested that how to make use of it to tackle this problem. As the first idea comes up will be the argument principle